# how to disable / remove yellow highlight from angular table on click

Tags: angular, material-ui, angular-material, angular-material-table

how would I disable the yellow highlight that shows when a mat-row is clicked? Without disabling the click event.

I tried looking for attributes to disable but can only find ones for the ripple effect on hover. The on hover highlight, which is gray is fine. I want to remove the yello.w highlight on click
I've tried to set background-color to transparent and none but no luck. The classes are coming from global css styles and I was able to get the classes by inspecting.

```
light-theme .selectedTableRow.mat-row .mat-cell {
background-color: transparent !important;
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.